# Adding border to DIV content

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to add a border to my emded twitter post 
But it is not working.
I used the auto emded generator from official twitter site 
copied the code and paste it.
I have created `DIV` for the code I copied.
Now When I try to put a border around the frame 
Its simply now working.

```css
.twitter_page {
    /*float: right;*/
    padding: 0 218px 0 0;
        /* border: solid; */
    margin-right: -60px;
    /*margin-left: 54px;*/
    margin-top: -410px;
    border : solid 2px grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="social_page">

<div class="twitter_page">
              
                <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="350" data-height="400" href="https://twitter.com/AZLily_official?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by AZLily_official</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</div>

<div class="facebook_page">
                            
                     <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php? 
                    href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FAZLily.yuri&tabs=timeline&width=350&height=400&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" width="350" 
                    height="400" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
  </div>



  </div>
```

If I do this way, Whole `DIV` gets border and I cant seem to reduce the width of the `DIV` , 
But I am not trying to border the `DIV`, Instead I am trying to border >br> the twitter frame. 
Is it possible?

Comment: @svr_sum I did what you said, I can see border, but the DIV width is not same as twitter frame, so the border stretches out longer than the frame. Here is the [Screenshot](https://ibb.co/hHa0X9).

Comment: Yeah i think this should do it. You can adjust the height and width of the div tag itself :                                                               <div class="twitter_page" style="width:350px;height:350px;">

Comment: @svr_sum Yes I tried to set H and W of DIV by css too, But the twitter frame decreases too. Here is the [Screenshot](https://ibb.co/cnpNep)

Comment: It worked for me ! [here is the link](https://jsfiddle.net/51z0n296/9/) I had done some changes in CSS too.

Comment: @svr_sum It did work, but it created new problem., It didnt align with FB frame corresponding. Why is that If I move Twitter class, FB class too.

Comment: It doesn't . Add position:relative. [here](https://jsfiddle.net/51z0n296/12/)

Comment: Can you add your answer on Answer post? So that I can Tick as answer?

Comment: Added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve the problem.
1) Changing the size of twitter div tag by setting width and height (inline/through CSS).
2) Setting the position:relative property to adjust position arbitrarily.

```css
.twitter_page {
    /*float: right;*/
    padding: 0px 0 0;
        /* border: solid; */
    margin-right: 0px;
    position:relative;
    left:20%;
    /*margin-left: 54px;*/
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border : solid 2px grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="social_page">

<div class="twitter_page" style="width:350px;height:350px;">
              
                <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="350" data-height="400" href="https://twitter.com/AZLily_official?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by AZLily_official</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</div>

<div class="facebook_page">
                        <br/>  <br/>
                     <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php? 
                    href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FAZLily.yuri&tabs=timeline&width=350&height=400&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" width="350" 
                    height="400" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
  </div>



  </div>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/51z0n296/12/) is the jsfiddle link.

Comment: This solved my problem. But ran into new issue with now FB border. The top part of border seems longer now. ;/ [Screenshot](https://ibb.co/fk6FX9)

Comment: Set both the same size. <div class="facebook_page" style="width:350px;height:350px;">

Comment: Yes both are set to same H and W . But nochange in FB DIV height. Here is the link to the [website](http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/).

Comment: Use the same CSS tag for both the div's. Like this: .twitter_page,.facebook_page{...............} . will fix the issue.Welcome!

Comment: I solved it. I had `<br>` Tag . Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

In twitter_page class, Set

```
padding: 0px;
display: inline-block;
```

This should work.

Comment: totally different from what being questioned. But If I dont set that value,I wont get the place where I want to insert the frame.

Comment: I didn't read your problem under the code.! That's why I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...
(just add a inner div in twitter_page and set border)

```css
.twitter_page {
    /*float: right;*/
    padding: 0 218px 0 0;
        /* border: solid; */
    margin-right: -60px;
    /*margin-left: 54px;*/
    margin-top: -410px;
}

.in_twitter_page {
    border : solid 2px grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="social_page">

<div class="twitter_page">
  <div class="in_twitter_page">
  <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="350" data-height="400" href="https://twitter.com/AZLily_official?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by AZLily_official</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="facebook_page">
                            
                     <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php? 
                    href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FAZLily.yuri&tabs=timeline&width=350&height=400&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" width="350" 
                    height="400" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
  </div>



  </div>
```